# C# - Одинаковые данные в массиве

Tags: c#, массивы

Допустим есть массив: `string[] names = new {"иван", "катя", "максим", "катя", "катя", "иван", "лёша"}` Мне нужно получить имя, которое встречается большее кол-во раз. Т.е. в данном примере я должен получить `катя`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этой цели можно использовать LINQ:

```
string name = names.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).First().Key
```

Answer (score 2):

Очень часто требуется такой функционал - выбор элемента со значением, которое является максимальным по некоторому критерию.

Он есть в библиотеке [morelinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)

Приведу несколько упрощенный вариант метода `MaxBy` из этой библиотеки:

```
static class EnumerableHelper
{
    public static T MaxBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, int> selector)
    {
        var max = default(T);
        int? maxKey = null;
        foreach (T candidate in source)
        {
            int candidateKey = selector(candidate);
            if (!maxKey.HasValue || candidateKey > maxKey.Value)
            {
                max = candidate;
                maxKey = candidateKey;
            }
        }
        if (!maxKey.HasValue)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Последовательность не содержит элементов");
        return max;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
string name = names.GroupBy(s => s).MaxBy(g => g.Count()).Key;
```

Этот вариант эффективнее, чем вариант с сортировкой, предложенный в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/724728/218063)

Еще вариант, который также не использует сортировку и имеет сложность O(n):

```
string[] names = { "иван", "катя", "максим", "катя", "катя", "иван", "лёша" };
var dict = names.GroupBy(s => s).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
int max = dict.Values.Max();
string name = dict.First(d => d.Value == max).Key;
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать словарь

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary =
    new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Проходя по массиву, добавляете значение слова в словарь, если его нет, или увеличиваете значение на 1, если уже есть.

```
dictionary.Add("катя", 1);
```